# How to detect if google chrome rss plugin is installed?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, google-chrome

I'm working on a word press project. I noticed that rss is not working fine on google chrome. After I googled about it, it turned out that I need to install a plugin for google chrome so rss works. I want to know how to detect if the plugin is installed or not in case the user is using chrome browser. 
Currently I'm doing the following:

`function is_chrome()`
 `{`
  `return(eregi("chrome", $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']));`
`}`

`if(is_chrome())`
`{`
 `// I want to check if plugin installed or not here.`

`}`

Comment: If the existence of the plugin is exposed to websites then I'll be surprised. If that information is sent to the server where PHP can read it, then I'll be astonished.

Comment: What do you mean David? Is that impossible to do?

Comment: It could possibly modify the user-agent string to announce its existence but I very much doubt that it does.

Comment: Ben, Can you be more clear please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot detect browser plugins via PHP.
You need to use JavaScript and then call a PHP script with an argument telling it if the JavaScript detected the plugin or not.

Additionally, DO NOT use ereg/eregi at all - use preg_match if you need regular expressions.
However, regular expressions are overkill for a "string a in string b" check.
Use this instead:

```
function is_chrome() {
    return stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'chrome') !== false;
}
```

Comment: what is the name of the plugin that I'm supposed to check about on java script?